# Am using karate with visual studio and want to connect to a remote linux and run commands from a feature file

Tags: ssh, karate

When I try to do same using karate.exec or in anyway it either halts near connection or throws below error in some instances:
DEBUG com.intuit.karate - Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

TRied appending with -t but no help

I followed below steps to establish ssh between my local windows and a remote linux:

1. Generate SSH key pairs
2. Transfer the public key to the server and copy it to the .ssh folder.
3. Enable SSH Tunneling by setting AllowTcpForwarding and StrickMode No

From windows cmd i could succesfully connect without password using "ssh -i %USERPROFILE%/.ssh/linux_rsa root@10.00.00.00"

When I try to do same using karate.exec or in anyway it either halts near connection or throws below error in some instances:
DEBUG com.intuit.karate - Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

TRied appending with -t but no help

Comment: I think you need to figure this out on your own, I have no suggestions